# Watchdog Timeout on SPIFFS.begin or SPIFFS.format

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, spiffs

I'm using an ESP-12E NodeMCU board from [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010O1G1ES) with the Arduino IDE. It's been working without any problems but now I'm trying to use SPIFFS to store data and I'm getting a Watchdog Timeout after 8 seconds when I call either SPIFFS.begin or SPIFFS.format.

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,7)

wdt reset
```

I've run the example CheckFlashConfig sketch and it reports a size mismatch.  IDE size of 4M and real size of 1M. I'm using the Adruino IDE board definition for NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module) with a flash setting of 4M (3M SPIFFS).

```
Flash real id:   001440C8
Flash real size: 1048576

Flash ide  size: 4194304
Flash ide speed: 40000000
Flash ide mode:  DIO
Flash Chip configuration wrong!
```

Here's the full code of the CheckFlashConfig sketch:

```
/* 
 ESP8266 CheckFlashConfig by Markus Sattler

 This sketch tests if the EEPROM settings of the IDE match to the Hardware

 */

    void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    }

void loop() {

    uint32_t realSize = ESP.getFlashChipRealSize();
    uint32_t ideSize = ESP.getFlashChipSize();
    FlashMode_t ideMode = ESP.getFlashChipMode();

    Serial.printf("Flash real id:   %08X\n", ESP.getFlashChipId());
    Serial.printf("Flash real size: %u\n\n", realSize);

    Serial.printf("Flash ide  size: %u\n", ideSize);
    Serial.printf("Flash ide speed: %u\n", ESP.getFlashChipSpeed());
    Serial.printf("Flash ide mode:  %s\n", (ideMode == FM_QIO ? "QIO" : ideMode == FM_QOUT ? "QOUT" : ideMode == FM_DIO ? "DIO" : ideMode == FM_DOUT ? "DOUT" : "UNKNOWN"));

    if(ideSize != realSize) {
        Serial.println("Flash Chip configuration wrong!\n");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Flash Chip configuration ok.\n");
    }

    delay(500000);
    }
```

Comment: does reflashing with different IDE settings fix it?

Comment: I tried flashing with esptool.py and flashed 2.1.0 (was 1.5.3) but there's no change in the CheckFlashConfig results.

Comment: Please post your full code, otherwise we can't reproduce it. If you really bought a `ESP-12E` it should be 32 MBit/4Mbyte. Can you tell us the output of `esptool.py flash_id`?

Answer (score 0):

I bought a 2nd Amica NodeMCU unit from another vendor and had no problems.  I'm chalking this up to bad hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be caused by inappropriate power supply. I know from my own experience that the Arduino Uno and most USB-TTL converters cannot safely deliver enough current to the ESPs. If you're not already, consider using a dedicated power supply circuit that are connected to a USB power source.